# How to have proper CSS style in PDF made from wkhtmltopdf (PHP wrapper), provided html from Angular?

Tags: php, css, angular, pdf

I have an app in Angular 4, which sends part of the html to the PHP server on linux, which in turn uses `wkhtmltopdf` (using a PHP wrapper) to make the PDF and send it back to browser to display it. The pdf is made and displayed after that, but it is not styled - at all -  as I can see. How to make the PDF with the proper CSS style in this manner? This is the code that Angular sends to the PHP part:

```
public getPdf() {
    const html = this.pdfEl.innerHTML;

    alert(html);

    this.rest.post(
      '/pdf',
      { html },
      {
        headers: new Headers(),
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
      }
    ).subscribe(
      (value) => {
        //alert('subscribe receiver in pdf button directive');
        this.url = URL.createObjectURL(value.blob());
        open(this.url);
      });

  }
```

Comment: did you try to set in the headers the document type (pdf)?

Comment: You mean to set the document type from angular to PHP? But shouldn't I be sending the html raw? This is the whole point of the process....

Comment: no, I meant the http request content type in headers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) and from php back to angular. Or I misunderstood your problem, don't you have a problem by displaying the processed pdf?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation for wkhtmltopdf to find out how to do the styling

Comment: There is no documentation about this, or at least I couldn't find anything.